# Sporadic Routes Not Found with material-ui and react-router-dom

Tags: material-ui, react-router-dom

I've an application router defined below:

```
<Router provider={createBrowserHistory()}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/register" component={RegistrationPage} />
    <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
    <Route component={NoMatch} />
    <Redirect to="/page-not-found" />
  <Switch>
</Router>
```

And I'm forwarding links using `Link` from MUI and `NavLink` from `react-router-dom` like so:

```
<Link button exact component={NavLink} to={'/login'}>
<LinkText>Login</LinkText>
</Link>
```

However, upon clicking the link, the user is presented with the default `NoMatch` component.

I've put a console.log in my `NoMatch` component and it looks like when the 404 is encountered, the location object as an additional wrapper object:

```
const NoMatch = ({ location }) => {
    console.log(location)
    const pathName = location.pathname || location.location.pathname
    return (
        <h3>No match for <code>{pathName}</code></h3>
    )
}
```

As seen with the `pathName` constant.

Any ideas what could be causing these routing problems?

EDIT: my problems go away if I use `BrowserRouter` instead of creating a `Router` with a history property

Comment: Normally you use a switch with routes, so it only matches one

Comment: ```import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
<Switch>
  <Route path = '/path1' component={ component1 } />
  <Route path = '/path2' component={ component2 } />
  <Route path = '/path3' component={ component3 } />
  ...
</Switch>
```

Comment: @GregM apologies, forgot to add the `Switch` to the example code.